# Invoking soap services and rest apis using Dropwizard framework

Tags: spring, rest, soap, cxf, dropwizard

I have a requirement to expose my business logic in RESTFul API. One of my colleague mentioned Dropwizard seems to be quite good. However i would like to know if it suits my requirements. My requirement is to invoke multiple SOAP services and REST APIs to build the application logic.

Does dropwizard have anything native support for consuming soap services / rest apis ?
 or 
i should integrate with other frameworks like Spring, CXF ? If i use CXF or Spring, i am aware that i will need to generate the JAXB annotated classes, Service endpoint interfaces etc, provide cxf beans and inject the dependencies into my code and implement business logic.

Pls let me know if the requirements can be met with just dropwizard without any other frameworks like spring, cxf etc ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can invoke external REST Services using this library

[dropwizard-client](http://dropwizard.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/client.html)

Demo example is given in this manual.